# Visual Studio Installer Extension Default Install Location

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to install my C# application using the [visual studio install extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d).

I've set the DefaultLocation for the Application Folder to

```
[ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer]\[ProductName]
```

I also tried

```
[DesktopFolder][Manufacturer]\[ProductName]
```

But it keeps putting all the files in Application Folder into C:\.

Any ideas?

Comment: Figured out that my problem is due to the fact my setup isn't being run with Admin rights. I'm now trying to figure out how to require Admin.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you need administrative right in order to write to `[ProgramFilesFolder]`.

As for restricting your setup program to run with Admin rights (run in Admin mode), you have to add a corresponding **launch condition**. Please refer to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/e5c47ca7-ebce-44ed-ae10-f3d0928521bc/installing-an-msi-in-admin-mode?forum=winformssetup) MSDN thread.